# .htaccess mod_rewrite rule not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get mod-rewrite to work in a htaccess file.

The URL I'm trying to achieve is:

```
blog/{id}-{title}/
```

So for example:

```
http://localhost/blog.php?id=12&title=this-is-a-test
```

Would become:

```
http://localhost/blog/12-this-is-a-test/
```

No what I've been trying is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z-])/$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

When I go to `http://localhost/blog/12-this-is-a-test/` I get a 404 error but if I go to `http://localhost/blog.php` the test page with the test text displays as expected.

Maybe I've written the rule incorrectly, if so can anyone suggest edits or are there any good tutorials, I've been reading through the http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html but haven't been able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated or even pointing me in the right direction, thanks.

### EDIT:

I was getting this on every link that the redirect rule applied:

```
http://localhost/C:/Apache/htdocs/test5/blog/1-Lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet
```

After I added in the below to the vhost:

```
<Directory "{path}">
    Options All               
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And I had to clear out the browser cache as it was also causing issues. Once these two actions where taken, anubhava's answer below worked and solved my issues.

Comment: So what is not working with this rule? What URL did you try in your browser?

Comment: The rule, when I got to the URL (http://localhost/blog/12-this-is-a-test/) I get a 404 error, but when I got to blog.php I get the test text displaying. Mod_rewrite is enabled as I've checked and tested already.

Comment: Did you try my rule as suggested below? Also do you have other rules too?

Comment: @anubhava, worked perfectly, took me a bit of time to get it working as there was an issue with `AllowOverride All` option missing from the vhost setup and another issue with the browsers cache, once both these where sorted the rule worked grand, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is missing quantifier `+` which is causing 2nd capture group to fail since it is expecting only 1 character:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also better to turn off `MultiViews` since your php file name `blog.php` is same as directory name `blog`.